# Drupal Error Message Help: User warning: The following module is missing from the file system: reference_dialog

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am receiving this error message in my Drupal reporting log every time someone visits a page on my site:

> User warning: The following module is missing from the file system: reference_dialog. For information about how to fix this, see the documentation page. in _drupal_trigger_error_with_delayed_logging() (line 1128 of D:\htdocs\guides\includes\bootstrap.inc).

I have looked and looked for an answer but cannot find out exactly what I should do. 
Here we are the two pages I have already reviewed:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2487215 and https://www.drupal.org/node/2767187

If anyone can helps me, please let me know.

Thank you,
Garret

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Missing module is: https://www.drupal.org/project/references_dialog  So do you have it installed or not?

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1). Download and install https://www.drupal.org/project/references_dialog aside other contrib modules;

2). Uninstall useless modules from your drupal 7 install (probably, references_dialog) (path: "/admin/modules/uninstall");

3). Test;

Answer (score 0):

The specified module is missed in your files ie the reference_dialog module does not exist in your module folder  but you might have enabled the module and areference exist in database.So you get this error message.

To resolve :

- Download this module.

if you don't use this module

- Disable and uninstall it.
- Remove the module from modules folder

.

Answer (score 0):

All advice from above is generally correct but with references_dialog there is a bug from the history of the module. The Problem  is fixed in 7.x-1.0-beta2 so update.

Answer (score 0):

The warning points to reference_dialog, but the system name of the module is references_dialog. If this warning exists after disabling or removing the module you can get rid of it by executing the following database query:

```
delete from system where name='references_dialog';
```